# WHERE clause in SOQL query to history object (to custom field)

Tags: soql, query, history-tracking, workbench

I am querying in the Workbench with SOQL.
I need to query a history object to a custom field, but I want to see changes only to a certain field. What is the syntax to say `WHERE Field = MyTargetField` ?

I tried this:

```
SELECT Field, NewValue, OldValue 
FROM MyCustomObject__History
WHERE Field = myTargetField__c
```

but this generates an error:

> MALFORMED_QUERY:
>   WHERE Field = myTargetField__c
>
> ERROR at Row:3:Column:14
>   Bind variables only allowed in Apex code

Comment: Just a note, whenever you get an error message you should include its text ***verbatim***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the value in single quotes (`'...'`):

```
SELECT Field, OldValue, NewValue
FROM MyObject__History
WHERE Field = 'Custom_Field__c'
```

Comment: I tried that, and that returns empty, it does not match with my target field.

Comment: @ASignor Are you sure you actually have history records where that field has changed?

Comment: Actually I'm not. You are probably right. Thank you.

Comment: Easy enough to verify. Just change the value in that field on an existing record. :)